# d3 - gif not showing up in arc?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm struggling with my code and getting a gif to appear on each of my arcs that I've drawn using d3.js.

Say I have a bunch of arcs on the page with the class '.arc'. I select them all using this:

```
   d3.selectAll('.arc')
  .append('svg:image')
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", 0)
  .style("top", 0)
  .attr('width', 200)
  .attr("height", 200)
  .style("z-index", 200)
  .attr("href", function (d) {
    return "snow-1.gif";
  })
```

I see them in the dom, they are bound to all the arcs but they're not visible on the page? When I use the inspector, they have no x or y and don't even appear despite being in the HTML. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you try to put the different values on the .attr and style quotation mark?

Comment: I did but no joy on that one